# kill the searchd sphinx process from php

Tags: php, sphinx, centos6

I couldn't kill the searchd process in Linux/Centos from php file, however I can do that directly from ssh

```
 public function doStop()
    { 

    $command = '/usr/bin/killall -9 searchd';

     exec($command);   
        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: Under which user do you run your PHP script and under which user you run command from shell?

Comment: Why on earth do you want php to have the ability to kill a process that is not a child process of php? (you can do it, just not if php and searchd are running as different users, which they are by default). daemons should be managed using supervisord/upstart/start-stop-daemon, not by sending signals from php scripts on a webserver that is probably public

Comment: I'm running both under same user , also the php is executing multiple processes unless kill
Also what you recommend if I want to kill process through php??

Comment: `killall -9` - ie SIGKILL is also absolutely the **wrong** way to shutdown sphinx. Its the last resort if all other methods fail, and usually only possible from root. You should be sending SIGTERM(15) to the **single** searchd process listed in the pid file. `searchd --stop` is a nice shortcut to do that (ie searchd will lookup the correct process and send it a signal)

Comment: I checked well the php file under laptopli account however the process is ran by root so how I kill process running by root from php file?

is it possible to do this?

Comment: @alan it's possible, but nobody without malicious intent will ever tell you to run PHP as root. It's really, really bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used C++ wrapper file to execute the command
it works fine now